# Nested #Each values are not available outside of the context

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I'm having a nested each pair like this:
{{#each goal in goals}}

```
<template name="task">
{{#each goal in goals}}
 {{#each task in relatedTasks goal}}
<li>
<span class="text task"><a href="#modal-taskedit" data-toggle="modal"><strong>{{task.taskName}}</strong></a> to {{goal.goalName}}<br> taskid: {{task._id}}
{{task.taskPostpone}}</span>
    {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Tasks" operation="update" doc=task._id}}
  Update {{task.taskName}}
{{/afModal}}
</li> 
      {{/each}}
 {{/each}}    

</template>
```

and would like to get the value of the task._id in my client.js like here:

```
Template.task.events({
    'click .task': function() {
    Session.set("selectedTask", this._id);
        //console.log(this._id);
        //console.log(goal._id);
        console.log(task._id);
        //console.log('Click event happened: this._id saved as selectedItem Session variable.');
  } 
  });
```

When I click on a task I receive this error on the console: "undefined" and I don't really understand the reason behind. I did some research and found a possible solution: Maybe 'click .task': function(task) should receive the task context or input so it could be able to grasp the meaning of this._id.
I have a {{#afModal doc=task._id}} which also should receive the value of task._id and does not seem to work, although it is placed in the right context I think.
I have a feeling that the two issues are related somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `{{#each goal in goals}}` loop syntax does not change the data context within the loop ([see docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#each)). It simply adds a `goal` variable for use in your spacebars template.

One solution would be to move the contents of the `{{#each task in ...}}` loop to another template like so.

```
<template name="task">
    {{#each goal in goals}}
        {{#each task in relatedTasks goal}}
            {{> goalTask goal=goal task=task}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="goalTask">
    <li>
        <span class="text task">
            <a href="#modal-taskedit" data-toggle="modal"><strong>{{task.taskName}}</strong></a>
            to {{goal.goalName}}<br>
            taskid: {{task._id}} {{task.taskPostpone}}
        </span>
        {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Tasks" operation="update" doc=task._id}}
            Update {{task.taskName}}
        {{/afModal}}
    </li>
</template>
```

Your event handler would then look like this.

```
Template.goalTask.events({
    'click .task': function() {
        console.log(this.goal._id);
        console.log(this.task._id);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with events in nested objects, how to get the data context of the object that was clicked on?

The simplest way to approach this problem is to create a template for each level of nesting. The proper context is then provided automatically.

```
<template name="goals">
{{#each goals}}
  {{#each task}}
    {{> task}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="task">
<li>
  <span class="text task"><a href="#modal-taskedit" data-toggle="modal">
  <strong>{{task.taskName}}</strong></a> to {{goal.goalName}}<br>
  taskid: {{task._id}}{{task.taskPostpone}}</span>
  {{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Tasks" operation="update" doc=_id}}
    Update {{task.taskName}}
  {{/afModal}}
</li>
</template>
```

Then your event handler can be defined on the *inner* task template with the data context automatically being the individual task and not the data context of the outer template.

```
Template.task.events({
  'click .task': function(){
    Session.set("selectedTask", this._id);
  } 
});
```

Comment: This method would only give you access to the properties of `task` within your second template. He needs access to both `task` and `goal`.

Comment: You can always access the parent's properties as well using `Template.parentData(n)` [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)